# undefined is not a function React native

Tags: javascript, react-native

My code is the following. I get ***undefined is not a function (evaluating '_this.storeAPIToken(responseJson.APIToken)')*** error

```
async function storeAPIToken(APIToken) {
    try {
        await AsyncStorage.setItem('@auth:APIToken', APIToken);
    } catch (error) {
        console.log("STORE API", error);
    }
}


const verifyOTPResponse = (dispatch, responseJson) => {
    console.log("checkOTPAPIStatus", responseJson.status);
    if (responseJson.status == "OK") {
        console.log("verifyOTPEntered OK");

        console.log('Token', responseJson.APIToken);
        this.storeAPIToken(responseJson.APIToken);

        firebase.auth().signInWithCustomToken(responseJson.token).then(() => {
            console.log("Login successfulx");

            dispatch({
                type: types.LOGIN_SUCCESS,
                payload: 1
            });

        }).catch(function(error) {
            var errorCode = error.code;
            var errorMessage = error.message;

            dispatch({
                type: types.LOGIN_FAIL,
                payload: 0
            });

        });
    } else {
        dispatch({
            type: types.OTP_VERIFICATION_FAIL,
            payload: loginStatus
        });
```

The responseJson.APIToken is not null it has value when I console logged it

Comment: The error you got is on `_this.storeAPIToken`

Comment: `verifyOTPResponse` doesn't have a `storeAPIToken` function. using `this` is wrong. remove `this` and try again please

Comment: it seems (obvious) that the error is referring to the fact that `this.storeAPIToken` is `undefined` - perhaps you don't need `this.` when calling that function

Answer (score 1):

Remove `this.` from the line calling `this.storeAPIToken(responseJson.APIToken);`. **this** context that refers at that line is different from the one to `storeAPIToken`.